# Reading json from file in Karate feature fails with js evaluation failed error

Tags: karate

I'm using [Karate Netty](https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/master/karate-netty#standalone-jar), version 0.9.6 on Windows 10 with openJDK 14.0.2.

I'm trying to read data from a json file in a feature file.
The following code fails:

```
Scenario: Get the credit balance
  * def data = read('classpath:examples1/user_credit_balance_get.json')
```

My console output looks as follows:

```
Karate version: 0.9.6
======================================================
elapsed:   2.31 | threads:    1 | thread time: 0.02
features:     1 | ignored:    0 | efficiency: 0.01
scenarios:    1 | passed:     0 | failed: 1
======================================================
failed features:
features.protect_a_prospect: protect_a_prospect.feature:4 - evaluation (js) failed: read('classpath:examples1/user_credit_balance_get.json'), java.lang.RuntimeException: evaluation (js) failed: ?{
    "session_data": {
        "user_id":  "101",
        "session_id":  "dslkdaskljd",
        "token":  "02389poasklj"
    },
    "call_data":  {
        "user_id":  "101"
    }
}, javax.script.ScriptException: <eval>:2:18 Expected ; but found :
    "session_data": {
                  ^ in <eval> at line number 2 at column number 18
stack trace: jdk.scripting.nashorn/jdk.nashorn.api.scripting.NashornScriptEngine.throwAsScriptException(NashornScriptEngine.java:477)
stack trace: com.intuit.karate.ScriptBindings.eval(ScriptBindings.java:155)

com.intuit.karate.exception.KarateException: there are test failures !
        at ...(.)
```

This leads me to believe that Karate is trying to read my json file as if it were JavaScript.
What could be the reason for this behaviour?

-- Edit --
Using `karate.readAsString` instead of `read` works as a workaround for me:

```
Scenario: Get the credit balance
  * def data = karate.readAsString('classpath:examples1/user_credit_balance_get.json')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is mighty confusing, you say Karate mocks but then you show the log for a Karate test. Karate should never try to evaluate a `*.json` file.

I think the best thing to do is to follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Actually I did not say anything about Karate mocks. Could you please elaborate?

Comment: Tbh I'm fairly new to Karate and the approach of testing like this. If I understand correctly, the feature files are mocks then? 
And yes, this is part of a test which I intended to write, but it failed way before it was supposed to. 
What would you have expected other than the log for a test?
Thank you for your time!

Comment: @PatrickKlein "karate netty" is known as API mocks. sounds like you are using the standalone JAR / ZIP distribution. I still don't know why you get the error reading a JSON file - other than a log, what I expect is given in the link in my answer. but if `readAsString` works for you, go with it